# While developing a package for Atom, how to write to a JSON file inside the package folder?

Tags: javascript, json, persistence, atom-editor

I'm developing a package for the Atom text editor, and in order for that package to work, it reads some JSON files that act as a simple database. Also, those JSON files should be periodically updated with data obtained from a public spreadsheet, thus they must be written to.

The problem, however, is that using `fs.writeFile`, paths are relative to the user's home folder, not to the package folder. While I could use a path like `.atom/packages/package-name/file.json`, to my limited knowledge of Atom packages, that does not feel like a good practice (or is it?).

Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem using relative paths in your script like so:

```js
const pathToJson = path.resolve(__dirname, 'file.json`);
// next: write data to JSON
```

However, if you *really* want to use absolute paths, there are several options.

**Atom API**

You can use the Atom API inside your package, which exposes the [`resolvePackagePath()`](https://flight-manual.atom.io/api/v1.45.0/PackageManager/) method:

```
const packagePath = atom.packages.resolvePackagePath('name-of-your-package');
const pathToJson = path.resolve(packagePath, 'file.json`);
// next: write data to JSON
```

You can combine this with the following snippet to retrieve the package name from the manifest:

```
const { name } = require('./package.json');
```

**3rd party package**

The [`atom-read-manifest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/atom-read-manifest) package allows you to do the same without having to specify the name of your package – but that's a question of personal taste, I guess.

```
const { readManifest } = require('atom-read-manifest');
// or use readManifestSync

(async () => {
    const { name } = await readManifest();

    const packagePath = atom.packages.resolvePackagePath(name);
    const pathToJson = path.resolve(packagePath, 'file.json`);
    // next: write data to JSON
})();
```

One final note: If your package is writing the data to the JSON, there are probably better ways to achieve the same. You need to consider that updating the package will overwrite your old `file.json`. Personally, I'd prefer to write the data to Atom's localStorage (or IndexedDB). If you prefer writing the data to a JSON file, then you should probably save it to `.atom/storage` instead.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `__dirname`. That solved the problem completely. Thanks!